# lighttpd htaccess translation !-d !-f and losing get query

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I currently try to translate a `.htaccess` file which is provided by the [chyrp](http://chyrp.net) installation routine to lighttpd via the `mod_rewrite` module.

The source `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase {$index}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Directory layout (webroot)

```
/chyrp/
/chyrp/includes/
/chyrp/admin/
/chyrp/feathers/
/chyrp/modules/
/chyrp/themes/
```

My current attempt

```
    index-file.names = ( "index.php" )
    url.access-deny = ( ".twig" )

    #taking care of the directory, check if it is one of the known ones, if so go on
    #if it is not, redirect to index
    url.rewrite-once = (
            "^/(|chyrp/)(admin|themes|feathers|modules|includes)(.*)$" => "/chyrp/$2$3",
            "^/(|chyrp/).*/$" => "/chyrp/index.php"
    )

    #check if files exists, if not rewrite to a index.php in the same directory
    url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
            "^/(|chyrp/)(admin|themes|feathers|modules|includes)(/(index.php)?(.*))?$" => "/chyrp/$2/index.php$5",
            "^/(|chyrp/)(.*)" => "/chyrp/index.php"
    )
```

It mostly works, except for the `search` functionality (testable here: [srctwig.com](https://srctwig.com)), which does not rewrite correctly (at least that's my guess) or somewhere the query gets lost.
The search routine itself works properly ([demonstration search with 0 results](http://srctwig.com/search/I+searched+something/))
A working demo of chyrp can be seen at [chyrp demo on apache2](http://chyrp.net/demo/)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the issue was, I was not aware of having to dissect the url in order to extract the `get` query string which I needed to preserve according to a [lighttpd mod_rewrite wiki entry](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite)

```
    url.rewrite-once = (
            "^/(|chyrp/)(admin|themes|feathers|modules|includes)/(.*)$" => "/chyrp/$2/$3",
            "^/(|chyrp/).+/(([^\?]+)?(\?.+)?)$" => "/chyrp/index.php$2"
    )

    url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
        "^/(|chyrp/)(admin|themes|feathers|modules|includes)(/([^\?]+)?(\?.+)?)?$" => "/chyrp/$2/index.php$5",
        "^/(|chyrp/)(([^\?]+)?(\?.+)?)$" => "/chyrp/index.php$2",
        "^/(|chyrp/).*$" => "/chyrp/index.php"
    )
```

Dissect:

## url.rewrite-once

```
"^/(|chyrp/)(admin|themes|feathers|modules|includes)/(.*)$" => "/chyrp/$2/$3",
```

These directories exist. Do not change anything except for ensuring the proper prefix if not alread there.

```
"^/(|chyrp/).+/(([^\?]+)?(\?.+)?)$" => "/chyrp/index.php$2"
```

Check if a non existant subdir was requested and check for `?`, treat everything after that as php `get` query and append it to the rewrite target.

## url.rewrite-if-not-file

```
"^/(|chyrp/)(admin|themes|feathers|modules|includes)(/([^\?]+)?(\?.+)?)?$" => "/chyrp/$2/index.php$5",
```

if the target does not exist just swap out the filename and keep the query (as above)

```
"^/(|chyrp/)(([^\?]+)?(\?.+)?)$" => "/chyrp/index.php$2",
```

go to the basefolder if none of the above matches and try to still pass the query

```
"^/(|chyrp/).*$" => "/chyrp/index.php"
```

this very last one is just for testing (put `foobarfailure.php` there to assert it never reaches that line)